# Pdo connection without database name?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a CMS and I want to make my client life easier so I create the database by myself. 
I encountered a problem while trying to do this. The database isn't created so I can't connect with a PDO connection and `mysql` is deprecated so I can't use it. Do you have any advice for me on how I can create a PDO connection before the database is created? like a `mysql_select_db()` alternative?

Comment: Why not just change the connection string before you create the PDO object? If you know the database name already, just add it to the string?

Comment: @Fluffeh: He wants to create the database dynamically from the Script, the database doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can start a PDO connection by this, correct me if I'm wrong:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", 'user', 'pass');
```

The difference from this with a normal connection is the removed part `dbname=[xx]`, as you see.

Also a free tip when you want to use a UTF-8 connection:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4", 'user', 'pass');
```

In order to the comment of `Yehonatan` you can select a database by:

```
$db->exec('USE databaseName');
```

Comment: Indeed. I just tested with this script `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;', 'user', 'pass');
print_r($db->query('SHOW DATABASES')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` and it worked ;)

Comment: @core1024: Chaining like this will give you headaches in a couple of months

Comment: This is just a test so nobody hurt here ;)

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to set the DB after that? like "mysql_select_db"?

Comment: I thound it - $pdoConnection->exec('USE databaseName');

Comment: Yes, see Yehonatan's answer :)

Comment: I'm getting error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set` with the dash in `UTF-8` but removing that as `charset=UTF8` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Using an empty string also works, eg `dbname=;`
no need to add more logic to get rid of all the dbname parts.

```
$db_name = '';

$pdo = new PDO(
    sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s',
        $db_host, $db_name, $db_charset),
    $db_user,
    $db_pass
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply drop the `dbname=` part:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;", "user", "pass");
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SHOW DATABASES");
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Gives me

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(18) "information_schema"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "cdcol"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "chica"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(9) "downloads"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "mysql"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(18) "performance_schema"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(10) "phpmyadmin"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(8) "rishumon"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "users"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(7) "webauth"
  }
}
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The only think I found to work is to use `$pdo->query('USE databasename')` to set the default database before you run any query.