# Why I'm not able to create a new database in MySQL using PDO? Is it necessary to have a database already present before creating a new one using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've installed the latest available version of **XAMPP Package** on my machine running on **Windows 10 Home Single Language** Edition.

I'm learning PHP and MySQL.

So, first of all in order to create a new database I wrote following code :

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDBPDO";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Database created successfully<br>";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();//Getting 'Notice : Undefined variable : sql' for this line
  }

  $conn = null;
?>
```

The database didn't get created and I received following error in output after running above file in a web browser :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in prog_1.php on line 16

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mydb'
```

Can someone please help me by correcting my code, so that I can further start studying the database concepts in actual manner?

Is it necessary to have a database already present when accessing the same using PDO?

**P.S. : The database titled 'mydb' is currently not present in MySQL RDBMS.**

Comment: More likely that your connect has failed

Comment: Please avoid asking 2 questions in one post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `$conn = new PDO()` fails because there isn't a database called `myDB` (`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049]`). Because that line fails your try catch statement will evaluate to the catch part before it declares the `$sql` variable. So when you try to access the `$sql` variable in the catch part it does not exist and will throw an `Undefined variable` error.

You'll have to move the `$sql` above the `$conn = new PDO()` line to fix the undefined variable error. To fix the missing database error you'll have to create a database called `myDB`.

```
try {
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDBPDO"; // moved it here
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // (...)
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage(); // no undefined variable
}
```

---

To connect to the database without selecting a specific database you'll have to change your `new PDO()` DSN to this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername", $username, $password);
```

For more information please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432418/5914775).

Comment: You are asking me to create a database myDB. So, I've to do it using phpMyAdmin only. Should I do it that way to make the PDO object creation line workable? Is it necessary to have a database already present when creating a new database using PDO?

Comment: Would you please add these points to your answer and update it so that I can accept the answer. Though +1 for now for helping me in understanding the concept.

Comment: @Badshah Please don't mind my last comment. You'll have to create it if you want to connect like that, you can omit the `dbname` variable from the string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432418/5914775).

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the DB name in your DSN connection string, and it looks like `mydb` doesn't exists.
Just remove that part from the DSN string and try again.